# Pentaho Double Counting Values

Tags: mdx, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I do not understand why this is happening. I've probably spent like 12 hours messing with this.

When I use Pentaho to build an analyzer report, all years have the same values with the same data.

For example, 2014, 2015, 2016, for the month of May, will all say 1000. When you drill down and click on 2014, it will have 2015 and 2016 included as well. Same for drilling down on 2015 and 2016.

Why in the world is this happening? :)

Comment: It's hard to give you any advice based on your input, but to me it looks like issue with join keys between your date dimension and the fact table. BTW, to debug the issue you can check SQL queries, generated by the analyzer.

Comment: Reason might be anything. I would suggest to query your DW first and if you get the expected results, then it is the time to revisit your Mondrian schema. I am pretty sure that there is something wrong in the Mondrian cube.

Comment: repetition in every cells usually indicates that there is no relationship - so I suspect there is a problem in your cube in respect of the relationship between Date and the Measure you're testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Here is what I discovered:

1. There was nothing wrong with my data in the table. Querying the table directly gave me exactly what I expected it to.
2. It was the Mondrian Cube that was the problem.
3. I set it so that "Quarter" and "Month" had unique members. I should not not done this.

Once I removed unique members from "Quarter" and "Month," everything worked perfectly. Thanks guys!